# Perl how to apply a regex only on variable which has two words?

Tags: perl

I want to apply a regex on lines where I have only 2 words. My file looks like this with variable numbers of spaces between the words in parentheses:

Politician_name:(Jose Maria Aznar | jose maria aznar | José María Aznar | josé maría aznar );
Politician_name:(Tony Blair | tony blair | Tony Blair | tony blair  );

I want to have as an output:

Politician_name:(Tony Blair | tony blair | Tony Blair | tony blair | **blair tony | Blair Tony**);

My code applies the regex on each line and I get false output like this:

Politician_name:(Jose Maria Aznar | jose maria aznar | José María Aznar | josé maría aznar | **maria jose | Maria Jose** );

This is my code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;

open(IN, $ARGV[0]) or die "Can't read file $ARGV[0]\n";
while (my $line=<IN>)
{
    my ($pol,$value) = split(/:/, $line);

    warn Dumper \$pol;
    chomp($value);
    $value=~ s/[  ]+/ /g;
    $value=~ s/\);//g;
    my $n;  
    $n = $1 if ($value =~ /\((.+?)\|/); 
    $n=~ m/(\w*)\s(\w*)/g;
    my $swapname="$2 $1";
    warn Dumper \$swapname;

    print "$pol: $value | $swapname );\n";

}
close(IN);
```

What do I need to do to stop handling 3-word names?

Comment: It looks like you might need to filter out [duplicate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3A%3AMoreUtils) names within a list.  You also need an inner loop to iterate over all the names within a list for a given politician.  Can a single entry have both double-word and triple-word names for the same politician?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$n=~ m/(\w*)\s(\w*)/g;   # Replace this regex with the one below
```

Use the below Regex to compare with `$n` and also you need to enclose it within an `if`, other wise your print will be executed for every input: -

```
my $n;  
$n = $1 if ($value =~ /\((.+?)\|/); 
if ($n =~ m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s*$/g) {  # Notice `$` to mark the end of 2 words..
    my $swapname="$2 $1";
    warn Dumper \$swapname;

    print "$pol: $value | $swapname );\n";
}
```

**But**, you are not taking into account the next value after `|`.. You need to do that.. It is just taking the first value..

**So, your output will  be: -**

```
Politician_name: (Tony Blair |tony blair | Tony Blair | tony blair | Blair Tony )
```

2nd `tony blair` is not getting used. You need to modify the code for that.

---

Actually **you need a loop** to iterate over every names, to make this code work properly.

---

**UPDATE** :- **I would rather change your code to: -**

```
# You should always use lexical variables as file handles..
open my $fh, '<', 'D:\demo.txt' or die $!;

while (<$fh>)  # Don't need use any extra variable here.. Default to $_
{
    my ($pol,$value) = split /:/;  # Do split on $_ by default
    warn Dumper \$pol;

    chomp($value);

    $value=~ s/[  ]+/ /g;
    $value=~ s/\((.*)\);/$1/g;

    my @name = split(/\|/, $value);  # Split your string to an array

    # Filter out array to remove duplicate

    my $_ = $name[0]; 

    if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s*$/g) {  

        # If first element contains 2 words, proceed with rest of the elements

        print "($value ";  # print the original string you want..

        # Append to it later on the reverse of other array elements

        foreach (@name) {
            if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s*$/g) {

                my $swapname = "$2 $1";
                warn Dumper \$swapname;

                print "| $swapname ";  # Print swapnames after $value
            }
        }
        print ");\n";  # End the string..
    }
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: You probably want a `\s*` after the `^` and another in place of `\s+` before the `$`.  The spacing is erratic, at best.

Comment: the regex is not working, i get the following error : syntax error at swapNames_regex.pl line 34, near "m/^(\w+)\s(\w+)\s+$/g;"

Comment: it's because of the semi-colon, i deleted it, but still get an error : Use of uninitialized value $n in pattern match (m//) at swapNames_regex.pl I defined all the variables !

Comment: @Rohit Jain...there is something ron with this regex  `if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s*$/g)`

Comment: I can't run the code because of this regex `if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s*$/g)`

Comment: @Rohit Jain... i dont want to remove the duplicate, i want to keep them to print them with the names inverses. i want to keep this format in my output : Politician_name:(Tony Blair | tony blair | Tony Blair | tony blair | blair tony | Blair Tony);

Comment: hmmm, how can i get Tony Blair in a variable and the reverse in another variable, so i can print both of them ?

Comment: @Rohit Jain: i also want to keep the names which are composed more than 3 words. how can i print them out ?

Comment: @Rohit Jain: i want to apply the regex only on names with 2 words and the rest i want to print it without any modification

Comment: @Rohit Jain: i mean by modification the reverse of names.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: the output doesn't include the names composed more than 2 like :Politician_name:(Jose Maria Aznar | jose maria aznar | José María Aznar | josé maría aznar | maria jose | Maria Jose ); I get only Politician_name: (Tony Blair |tony blair | Tony Blair | tony blair | Blair Tony )

Comment: @Funmatica.. Replace both your `if's` with: - `if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)?\s*$/g)`

Comment: @Funmatica.. And if you want even more: -more than 3.. Use this regex instead : - (Notice we use `*` instead of `?` after (`\w+`)) ..       `if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)*\s*$/g)`

Comment: @Funmatica.. Ok, bro.. If you have any more problem.. Will solve it later.. Gotta go home :)

Comment: @Rohit Jain: if i replaced the if regex, it will reverse the names with 3 words ?

Comment: @Funmatica.. So, you want to reverse the names with more than 3 words??

Comment: @Funmatica.. Use thid Regex: -  **`if (m/^\s*(\w+)\s(\w+)((\s(\w+)){2,})?\s*$/g)`**  .. This will match names with 2 words, 4 words, 5 words, or more.. (But not **3 words**)

Comment: no just names with 2 words, but i want also to print out the rest, coz the code is omitting the names with 3 words and more

Comment: @Funmatica Can you stop extending the question in the comments please?  If you have a distinct, new question, then ask that, please.

Comment: Or you could just split on whitespace and count the resulting array.

Comment: @casperOne : it's the same qst i posted i my qst !

Comment: @Funmatica If you've accepted an answer, then there shouldn't be the need to extend the conversation this far after the fact.